# Is class/namespace-based code organization relevant in JavaScript/Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, project-organization

*Disclaimer:* I’m a Node.js newbie.

There’s a number of class-based languages in which you can/must use *namespaces* to organize your code, for example: Java, PHP, ActionScript 3… For a number of those languages, if you choose/have to use namespaces, there’s generally a set of common practices and conventions that govern project organization then:

- *Classes* form the basic code units, and responsibilities are spread across *multiple classes*.
- The class file hierarchy reside in a *single top-level directory* (most of the time: `src/` or `lib/`).
- Each source file contains a *single class definition* and nothing else.
- Each class resides at a specific level of a *namespace* (or *package*) hierarchy, which mirrors the filesystem; for example:

  - in Java: class `com.badlogic.gdx.Application` would be found in the `src/com/badlogic/gdx/Application.java` file
  - in PHP (with PSR-0): class `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel` would be found in the `src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php` file
- Foreign class symbols can be *imported* into the current scope via a specific statement:

  - in Java: `import com.badlogic.gdx.Application;`
  - in PHP: `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;`

I’m used to this type of project organization, but I do realize that it’s specific to class/namespace-based languages and that it might not match JavaScript/Node.js’ usual idioms. If I understand the concept of Node.js modules correctly, it’s *1 source file = 1 module*, but from what I’ve seen in a lot of NPM packages, a module usually export more than one symbol, and more often than not those exports are functions and not classes/constructors, so it’s pretty different from the conventions described above.

So, I have the following questions:

- In JavaScript/Node.js, is it relevant at all to think about distribution of responsibilities in terms of «classes only» (using either the traditional *constructor + prototype composition* method or the new `class` shorthand)?
- Is the type of project organization described above possible at all in the context of a Node.js project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In JavaScript/Node.js, is it relevant at all to think about distribution of responsibilities in terms of «classes only» (or «prototypes only» for that matter)?

In Javascript it's a choice rather than a mandate. You can go full OOP even file structure wise. Or just write modules as pure functions. I'd advise you to stick to the structure that's easier for others, who may want to understand your code, to follow. For example, the OOP style:

Let namespace be the path under src

```
/src/org/xml/XMLDocument.js
```

and have a class very similar to the popular OOP languages:

```
 // imports
 const fs = require('fs');
 const XMLNode = require('./XMLNode');

 // class def
 class XMLDocument extends XMLNode {

   // constructor
   constructor(filePath){
     ...
   }

   // property getter
   get filePath(){
     ...
   }

   // method
   function getElementsByName(name){
     ...
   }

 }

 // export class to outer world
 module.exports = XMLDocument;
```

Use the class

```
// import
const XMLDocument = require('./org/xml/XMLDocument');

// create an instance     
const doc = new XMLDocument('./mydoc.xml');
```

So yes, following an OOP structure is relevant when you tackle the problem the OOP way. And there are alternate ways as well.

Another "creator" oriented custom style:

```
 function createXMLDocument(filePath){
     const doc = {};
     doc._type = "XMLDocument";
     ... // make the object have XMLDocument features
     return doc;
  }

  function createDXMLDocument(filePath){
     const doc = cerateXMLDocument(filePath);
     doc._type = "DXMLDocument";
     ... // modify parent object with DXML features
     return doc;
  }
```

You see, there are some patterns the developer adheres to and write all project code in that style.

> Is the type of project organization described above possible at all in the context of a Node.js project?

A Node.js project can have any kind of code organisation because of certain features:

1. Javascript module system is nothing but referencing a js file present somewhere in file system. So there are no special restrictions on file placement. There are modules that are built in, or can be installed via npm.
2. Module exports can export one or multiple "things" to external world. So a lot of flexibility here as well.
3. Javascript itself can be easily written in many styles, functional, OOP, procedural etc. It allows developer to modify a lot of Javascript's own nature. Hence possibly "mimic" many programming styles.

Comment: It is also worth to mention namespaces in the code, not just in filenames (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230966/how-to-namespace-es6-classes-for-react-components)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this awesome and complete answer, that’s exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> In JavaScript/Node.js, is it relevant at all to think about distribution of responsibilities in terms of «classes only» (or «prototypes only» for that matter)?

To be honest I don't really understand this question. You should follow OOP principles if you use classes, but if you do not, you still need to find cohesion between your functions and organize them in modules and folders based on that.

> Is the type of code organization described above usual or relevant at all in the context of a Node.js project, and is it technically implementable without too much trouble?

Javascript modules don't have namespaces, which make things a bit easier (Remember that C# and c++ projects usually have a folder structure totally different than the namespaces). Use folders as namespaces and you'll be fine. There is no such rule that you can only have one class per source file. I usually start writing classes and functions in a single file, and reorganize into multiple files when the file grows big. JavaScript's module system is very flexible, you can organize the code literally any way you want.

> If not, what are the traditional ways of handling repartition of responsibilities and code reuse in a Node.js project?

The same as anywhere else.

Comment: Sure there is no «rule» per se that enforces the *one class per file* idiom, but it’s a well-established convention in a number of class/namespace-based languages. My question was really if it was possible to «mimic » that convention + namespaces in Node.js. Maybe my question wasn’t clear/specific enough, I’ve edited it.