# JS classes, static fields and namespace

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32231314/5057736) I have the following class:

```
com.temp.System = class {
    static initialize() {
        this.foo = 9;
        console.log("foo 1 is: " + this.foo);
    }

    static testMe() {
        console.log("foo 2 is: " + this.foo);
    }
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
{
    const System = com.temp.System;
    System.initialize();
    System.testMe();
}
```

And this is output:

```
foo 1 is: 9
foo 2 is: 9
```

And I have two questions:

1. What is the best way to create static fileds in such solution?
2. Why `this.foo` works although I don't create instances of this class?

Comment: 1. You have created those already 2. Because `System` is an object and objects in JS may have properties.

Comment: [Don't use `class`es with only static properties at all!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29895235/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best way to create static fields in such solution?

Do not use `class` syntax if you don't want to create instances of it.

```
com.temp.System = {
//                ^ simple object literal
    initialize() {
        this.foo = 9;
        console.log("foo 1 is: " + this.foo);
    },
    testMe() {
        console.log("foo 2 is: " + this.foo);
    }
};
```

> Why `this.foo` works although I don't create instances of this class?

Because it's not an instance property. You've created `System.foo = 9`. `this` in a method is just the object that the function was called on - which is the namespace object in your example `System.initialize()`.

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside a `static method` points to just the `class`, so when you called `initialize` it resulting in adding a property `foo` to the class instead of an instance. This is why it was defined when you called `testMe`

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use a plain good old object literal:

```
com.temp.System = {
  foo: 5,

  initialize() {
    console.log("foo 1 is: " + this.foo);
  },

  testMe() {
    console.log("foo 2 is: " + this.foo);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there's [no such thing as static properties in ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#_static-data-properties). The question I want to ask, however, is different: why do you need "static class properties"? How is that different from a constant or, if desired to be accessible from the outside of your class, an exported constant?

The link above gives an example of creating "static data properties" using either `Object.defineProperty` or just direct assignment to a class `MyClass.static = ...`. However, don't use it unless you clearly understand why.

Comment: Static properties are not immutable... `How is that different from a constant` it is definetly

Comment: @JonasW. you're right, thanks. I didn't think about mutability.